# Word made up of exactly 4 different letters using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

For example *reassesses* will match.  It contains exactly **4** different characters: 'r', 'e', 'a' and 's'.

My attempt is: `/^([a-z])([a-z])([a-z])([a-z])(\1|\2|\3|\4)(\1|\2|\3|\4)(\1|\2|\3|\4)$/`
(add as many `(\1|\2|\3|\4)` as required to match length of word)

However this will match only up to 4 different letters, and only if they are the first 4 characters.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: How does that regexp require that the letters be different?

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex for that

Comment: Haskell: `length (nub str) == 4`. Another solution: `length (group $ sort str) == 4`

Comment: There might be a way to do it using negative lookaround and back-references. But I agree with @JanDvorak.

Comment: I am required to use regex

Comment: I this even possible with regex of reasonable size?

Comment: @OhHo72 required, by whom? If it's by your teacher, what hints has he given to you?

Comment: The teacher said this can be achieved with use of back-references

Comment: It can be achieved. It won't be pretty by any means, however.

Comment: My battery is dead now, but I may write a solution when I get home.

Comment: Back references?  Really!? I wish more time would be spent on creating maintainable code.  Maintainability of code goes down with every regex, and much moreso with back references.

Comment: You could shorten your regex to `^([a-z])([a-z])([a-z])([a-z])(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)*$` so it would match words of any length, however, this regex still requires the four different letters to be the first four characters in the string.

Comment: I wish your professor would come on here and educate us. I'd definitely be curious of his solution.

Comment: There is only 1 solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
^([a-z])\1*+([a-z])(?:\1|\2)*+([a-z])(?:\1|\2|\3)*+([a-z])(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)*$
```

The use of [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) is essential in this pattern, because it forbids backtracking and avoids that the following capturing group matches a letter that has been found.

The possessive quantifier feature is available in Java (don't forget to double escape backreferences), but if you need to use the pattern in a language that doesn't have this feature, you can find several options to "translate" the pattern in my comment.

The above pattern is build to check a whole string, but if you want to find words in a larger string, you can use this (with eventually the case-insensitive option):

```
(?<![a-z])([a-z])\1*+([a-z])(?:\1|\2)*+([a-z])(?:\1|\2|\3)*+([a-z])(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)*(?![a-z])
```

Comment: This also matches if there are less than four unique characters. Negative lookahead could solve that, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak: possessive quantifiers are better in this case.

Comment: ... if available. You should probably offer both (+ some discussion and explanation, ideally)

Comment: I like this answer even without an explanation, just a note though it uses possessive quantifiers `*+` and won't work in JavaScript (Chrome/IE), C# or Python (2.7/3.3) without modification. Something like this will work though: `^([a-z])(?:\1*)+([a-z])(?:(?:\1|\2)*)+([a-z])(?:(?:\1|\2|\3)*)+([a-z])(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)*$`

Comment: @DeanTaylor: This pattern matches "abca". `(?:\1*)+` is slightly different from `\1*+` (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html for more informations). The OP seems to use Java, but you can make it work with C# replacing `\1*+` with `(?>\1*)`. For Javascript or the re module of Python, you can replace it with `(?=(\1*))\2` and `(?=((?:\1|\3)*))\4` for the next, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^([a-z])\1*([a-z])(\1*\2*)*([a-z])(\1*\2*\4*)*([a-z])(\1*\2*\4*\6*)*$
```

Edit to not match less than 4 unique (e.g. aaaa):

```
^([a-z])\1*(?!\1)([a-z])(\1*\2*)*(?!\1)(?!\2)([a-z])(\1*\2*\4*)*(?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\4)([a-z])(\1*\2*\4*\6*)*$
```

Comment: Also, this only matches 4 unique lower case _letters_. To match 4 unique _characters_, replace all [a-z] with `.`

Comment: +1, but I would use non-capturing groups for the repetitions, so the backreference are numbered from 1 to 4: `^([a-z])\1*([a-z])(?:\1*\2*)*([a-z])(?:\1*\2*\3*)*([a-z])(?:\1*\2*\3*\4*)*$`

Comment: This also matches if there are less than four unique characters. Negative lookahead could solve that, though.

Answer (score 1):

Definetly works -
This should cause an alignment that only composes 4 distinct char's of
a string >= 4 in length.

```
 #  ^(?=.*(.).*(?!\1)(.).*(?!\1|\2)(.).*(?!\1|\2|\3)(.))(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)+$

 ^ 
 (?=
      .* 
      ( . )
      .* 
      (?! \1 )
      ( . )
      .* 
      (?! \1 | \2 )
      ( . )
      .* 
      (?! \1 | \2 | \3 )
      ( . )
 )
 (?: \1 | \2 | \3 | \4 )+
 $
```

Perl test case:

```
if ("upepipipeu" =~ /^(?=.*(.).*(?!\1)(.).*(?!\1|\2)(.).*(?!\1|\2|\3)(.))(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)+$/)
{
      print "unique chars: '$1'  '$2'  '$3'  '$4'\n";
      print "matched:      '$&'\n";
}
```

Output >>

```
unique chars: 'i'  'p'  'e'  'u'
matched:      'upepipipeu'
```

Test case for @aliteralmind:

```
@Ary = ("aabbccdd", "dictionary", "reassess", "aaaa");

for( @Ary )
{
    if ("$_" =~ /^(?=.*(.).*(?!\1)(.).*(?!\1|\2)(.).*(?!\1|\2|\3)(.))(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)+$/)
    {
       print "unique chars: '$1'  '$2'  '$3'  '$4'\n";
       print "matched:      '$&'\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
       print "Failed-> '$_'\n\n";
    }
}
```

Output >>

```
unique chars: 'a'  'b'  'c'  'd'
matched:      'aabbccdd'

Failed-> 'dictionary'

unique chars: 'r'  'a'  'e'  's'
matched:      'reassess'

Failed-> 'aaaa'
```

Comment: @aliteralmind - Where do you get it doesn't work for 4 characters? There is a test case, it works..

Comment: @aliteralmind - I posted those strings in a test case. Do you dispute the results? The regex compells the correct solution every time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as regex, this is a brain-buster. Here is a non-regex solution. A function that uses a map to keep track of unique characters, and returns true when the maximum number of unique characters is reached.

```
import  java.util.Map;
import  java.util.TreeMap;

/**
   <P>{@code java ExactlyFourDiffChars}</P>
 **/
public class ExactlyFourDiffChars  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      System.out.println("aabbccdd: " + hasMoreThanXUniqueChars(4, "aabbccdd"));
      System.out.println("dictionary: " + hasMoreThanXUniqueChars(4, "dictionary"));
      System.out.println("reassesses: " + hasMoreThanXUniqueChars(4, "reassesses"));
   }
   public static final boolean hasMoreThanXUniqueChars(int maxAllowedChars, String str)  {
      Map<Character,Object> charMap = new TreeMap<Character,Object>();

      for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)  {
         Character C = str.charAt(i);
         if(!charMap.containsKey(C))  {
            charMap.put(C, null);

            if(maxAllowedChars-- == 0)  {
               return  false;
            }
         }
      }
      return  true;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java ExactlyFourDiffChars
aabbccdd: true
dictionary: false
reassesses : true
```