# Negative Regex for 4 input

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have positive expression:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()-_=+])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

Here I choose expression in which there are at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, digit and special character (**wrong**: `8$t` or `4EE`. **correct**: `R7e+` or `@6Jw`).

I need to make a negative expression for this. That is, look for any phrase in which all four characters at the same time do not occur (**wrong**: `A1a+` or `%2Ht`. **correct**: `1+a` or `w2B`).

How I can make this a negation?

Comment: How is `8$t 4EE` wrong? It contains "at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, digit and special character" as you specify.

Comment: @aliteralmind, are two different examples. badly separated them. sorry

Comment: Why do you need to negate it with regex? For example, `if(!matched) { //do stuff }`

Comment: customer's component only accept regex. any ideas, @aliteralmind ? ))

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152874/word-made-up-of-exactly-4-different-letters-using-regular-expressions.  You are pushing the boundaries of what regex can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that it is *not* pretty, what's wrong with

```
^(?!(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-!@#$%^&*()_=+])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])).*$
```

Also be careful, `-` is a special character inside of a character class. To treat it literally you need to put it at the beginning or the end or the class.

**Performance**

On a side note, if you want improved performances, you might want to take advantage of the possessive quantifier, in order to fail quicker when you need to.

The positive regex you posted could be changed into

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*+[A-Z])(?=[^-!@#$%^&*()_=+]*+[-!@#$%^&*()_=+])(?=[^0-9]*+[0-9])(?=[^a-z]*+[a-z]).*$
```

See the improved results here from regex101 (the debugger is launched from the bug-like icon on the left): [with possessive quantifiers](http://regex101.com/r/dY8vD9/#debugger) vs [no possessive quantifier](http://regex101.com/r/yX2iA1/#debugger).

You can obviously negate that one as well in the same way we did the first one.